# Why would D90 preset white balance be no good

Tags: nikon, white-balance

For the Nikon D90, how do I remove the preset white balance in Image d-0?

Comment: Your question is very unclear - please rephrase.

Comment: What is "Image d-0'?

Comment: Are you wanting to overwrite the custom preset, as George described, or just want to change the camera to use another preset (Auto, Daylight, etc?)

Answer (score 3):

In contrast to other presets, you do not need to remove d-0, you simply overwrite it with a new one.

1. Hold the "WB" button on the back of the camera.
2. While holding the WB button, select with the back dial "Pre" and with the front "d-0" (if you have reversed the dials in the options, it'll be the other way around)
3. Release the WB button. Now you have loaded/selected the d-0 preset. Time to overwrite it!
4. Press and hold the WB button for 3-4 seconds, until "PrE" starts flashing
5. While "PrE" flashes, take a photo for the preset (ideally a grey card if you have one)
6. If the camera was able to set the the white balance it'll flash "Good"
7. If it wasn't able, it'll flash "No Gd" (short for "no good"). Repeat step 4,5 and make sure you have a proper exposure (focusing shouldn't play a role).

That's it, you're all set! You have successfully overwritten the previous preset with the new -and now current- preset that you need.

The above procedure is also described in the camera manual.